# insert semi colon after 10 digit number

Tags: sed

I have lines that start like this: `2141058222 11/22/2017` and I want to append a `;` at the end of the ten digit number like this: `2141058222; 11/22/2017`.

I've tried sed with `sed -i 's/^[0-9]\{10\}\\$/;&/g'`  which does nothing.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why is `$` in your pattern?

Comment: suggested by someone, with or without there is nothing

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo "2141058222 11/22/2017" | sed -r 's/^([0-9]{10})/&;/'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "2141058222 11/22/2017" | sed 's/ /; /'
```

Output:

```
2141058222; 11/22/2017
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input is *always* in the format specified, *GNU* `cut` works, and might even be more efficient than `sed`:

```
cut -c -10,11- --output-delimiter ';' <<< "2141058222 11/22/2017"
```

Output:

```
2141058222; 11/22/2017
```

---

For an input *file* that'd be:

```
cut -c -10,11- --output-delimiter ';' file
```

Comment: More efficient in memory usage anyways -- `cut` is half the size of `sed`.